# How to make a percentage

Tags: c#, percentage

I'm very new to coding how can i change this code:

```
IEnumerator SpawnWave()
    {
        waveIndex++;

        for (int i = 0; i < waveIndex; i++)
        {
            SpawnEnemy();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        }
    }
```

To a code that adds 10% of the `WaveIndex` value.

Comment: `waveIndex = waveIndex * 1.1` will add 10%

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, but about modifying a mathematical expression

Comment: Hopefully my answer below can help you out, but I recommend to learn C# from the ground up and at least read about integral types (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w.aspx), floating point types (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ahet949.aspx) and operators (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173145.aspx) in C# first.

Answer (score 0):

### Probably More Complicated Than Expected

For a failsafe answer, I am missing the type of `waveIndex`. Because it is called "...Index" and the operator `++` is used, I assume it is an integer value (`waveIndex`is of type `int`).

---

**TL;DR**

Use `waveIndex = (int)Math.Ceiling(1.1 * waveIndex);`, instead of `waveIndex++;`and make sure, waveIndex is always bigger than 0. If the result of the multiplication is not an integer, the value will be rounded up to the next bigger integer value.

---

**Warning**

If you always add 10% to `waveIndex` and `waveIndex` can only store integer values (e.g. because it is of type `int`), you will never get from 1 to 2, because of the rounding effect.

So either you have to use another type for `waveIndex` than `int`, use `Math.Ceiling` and start with a `waveIndex` of 1 or bigger, use  `Math.Round` and start with a `waveIndex` of 5 or bigger or you have to start with a `waveIndex` of 10 or bigger.

---

**Detailed answer for integer values**

There are a lot of expressions that will add 10% to a numerical value. But I will only present two of them - hopefully the easiest ones, helping you to learn how to code.

I assume `waveIndex` is of type integer. So you have to cast the result back to an integer after the calculation. This is done by adding brackets around the mathematical expression and adding `(int)` before the opening bracket.

```
// First example for adding 10% to an integer.
waveIndex = (int)(1.1 * waveIndex);

// Second example for adding 10% to an integer.
waveIndex = (int)(waveIndex + 0.1 * waveIndex);
```

By default, the result will be rounded down to the next smaller integer value. To change this behaviour, you may use one of the following statements.

```
// Rounds e.g. 1.4 down to 1 and 1.5 up to 2.
waveIndex = (int)Math.Round(1.1 * waveIndex);

// Rounds e.g. 1.1 up to 2.
waveIndex = (int)Math.Ceiling(1.1 * waveIndex);
```

Because `Math.Ceiling`and `Math.Round` return results of type double, it has to be casted to an integer, by using`(int)` again.

So your complete code would e.g. look like the following version. It adds 10% to `waveIndex` and rounds the value down to the next smaller integer.

```
IEnumerator SpawnWave()
{
    waveIndex = (int)Math.Round(1.1 * waveIndex);

    for (int i = 0; i < waveIndex; i++)
    {
        SpawnEnemy();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 IEnumerator SpawnWave()
{
    waveIndex = waveAdd(waveIndex*1.1);
    for (int i = 0; i < waveIndex; i++)
    {
        SpawnEnemy();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    }
}
int wIndex=0;
private int waveAdd(int targetWaveIndex){
     wIndex++;
     if(wIndex<targetWaveIndex){
         waveAdd(targetWaveIndex);
     }else{
         return targetWaveIndex;
         wIndex=0;
     }
}
```

What else is there to say?? I speak through my magnificent code!